How to stop Loop Verification
being real I dont have a problem but I want to learn something that i didnt know, so I did a really simple word add and remove on Java, but when I want to verificate which word I have to remove, the system do the verification for every word know in the Set, and doing that he display one message for every word that get into the Loop verificating everyone of them, how can I set a method to only set a message for the word that I want?
I'm Brazilian and I'm never ever practice English just get into coding and start to watch some video and learned what you can see, and also I'm not using translator so if something is confusing, that's the answer hahahaha.
package PalavrasUnicas;


import java.util.*;

public class ConjuntoPalavrasUnicas {
    private final Set<String> conjuntoPalavras;
    public ConjuntoPalavrasUnicas(){
        this.conjuntoPalavras = new HashSet<>();
    }
    public void adicionarPalavra(String palavra){
        conjuntoPalavras.add(palavra);
    }
    public void removerPalavra(String palavra){

        String palavraRemover = ""; 
        for (String p: conjuntoPalavras){
            if (p.equalsIgnoreCase(palavra)){

                palavraRemover = p;
                System.out.println("Palavra encontrada.");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Palavra não encontrada.");
            }
        }

        conjuntoPalavras.remove(palavraRemover);
    }
    public void verificarPalavra(String palavra){
        String palavraVerificar = "";
        for (String p: conjuntoPalavras){
            if (p.equalsIgnoreCase(palavra)){
                palavraVerificar = p;
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println(" Palavra não encontrada.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Palavra Encontrada " + palavraVerificar);
    }
    public void exibirPalavrasUnicas(){
        for (String p : conjuntoPalavras){
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}



Hey guys, just solved

If you feel more comfortable with Portuguese, you can try https://pt.stackoverflow.com

If someone is curious on how to do it, just remove the loop and use contains() instead of equalsIgnoreCase(), since it can only be used if we are looping String per String. The contains() method searches if the word is on there and returns a boolean, just use an if statement for checking that boolean:
If it's true: just use the remove() method, because it's smart enough to remove the word just by the value of it. If it's false: throw an exception or just print to the console (like I did)
If you want to see that in code:
public void removerPalavra(String palavra){
    String palavraRemover = "";

    if (conjuntoPalavras.contains(palavra)){
        conjuntoPalavras.remove(palavra);
        System.out.println("Palavra encontrada.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Palavra não encontrada.");    
    }        
}


set.remove() returns whether the object was present, so you could further simplify this to System.out.println(conjuntoPalavras.remove(palavra) ? "encontrada" : "nâo"), with one lookup instead of two.
